# Logical operators not working as expected in SpEL

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I have a usecase where I have two boolean properties, based on which I need to derive a value of instance variable. Below is the code snippet:

```
@Value("${propFlag1:false}")
private Boolean flag1;

@Value("${propFlag2:false}")
private Boolean flag2;

@Value("${propFlag2:false && propFlag1:false}")
private Boolean flag3;

@Value("${propFlag1:false && propFlag2:false}")
private Boolean flag4;
```

Here, `propFlag1` and `propFlag2` are flags from properties file, having values `true` and `false` respectively.
Values are being injected correctly for `flag1` and `flag2`, but for `flag3` and `flag4`, the values injected are `false` and `true` respectively instead of `false` for both.
So, when I try using `&&`, it is not ANDing two values, rather it is injecting the value of first variable itself. What am I doing wrong here?

PS : I am new to SpEL

Comment: `"${propFlag1:false} && ${propFlag2:false}"` would yield a text like `"true && false"`. `"${propFlag1 && propFlag2}"` looks best. _Not sure._

Comment: It is giving me error, `Could not autowire field`, any other option I can try?
I have tried using `and` as well, no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [SpEL documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions), this should work:

```
@Value("#{${propFlag2:false} and ${propFlag1:false}}")
private Boolean flag3;

@Value("#{${propFlag1:false} and ${propFlag2:false}}")
private Boolean flag4;
```

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks.